Cannot compare the output of subprocess.check_output() not comparing with a string?
I have this below code in python:
p4status = subprocess.check_output(['p4', 'status', f'{str(getP4Root())}/{self.dev_pattern}/...'],
                                cwd=getP4Root(), env=self.env).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).strip()
print(p4status)
return f'{str(get4Root())}/{self.dev_pattern}/... - no file(s) to reconcile.' in p4status

The variable p4 status when printed gives the same string as it is matched to
f'{str(get4Root())}/{self.dev_pattern}/... - no file(s) to reconcile.'

but the check returns false somehow. Can't see any solution online.
sys.stdout.encoding used here is utf-8

I suggest you put print(f'{str(get4Root())}/{self.dev_pattern}/... - no file(s) to reconcile.') in the function, so you can see the two strings next to each other.

Also print their reprs, and make sure what you’re seeing is actually caused by the print and not coming from stderr (maybe use a debugger).

Are you saying the actual value of p4status is  f'{str(get4Root())}/{self.dev_pattern}/... - no file(s) to reconcile.' ?  i.e. it contains the letter f, then an open brace, then the letter s, etc?
